# auth0 remember last login never work for iOS

Tags: auth0

I have an ionic/angular 1.x application. I use Auth0 (auth0.com) to authenticate my users. When I was testing my app on the browser (using ionic serve), the auth0 can remember my last logged-in user credential.  However, when I deploy my app to a real device (iPhone), Auth0 wants me to type in user credential (username+password) every single time.

I tried to add `rememberLastLogin: true,` in my auth.signin() method, but it never work.  Below is my code snipped: I am wondering if anyone ever ran into the same situation and can give me some direction that I can check.  Thank you very much!

```
auth.signin({
      onestep: true,
      showIcon: true,
      rememberLastLogin: true,
      signupFooterText: "this line won't appear..",

      signupTitle: "don't show",
      icon: "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/trysoda/soda-red/256/Keys-icon.png",

      authParams: {
        scope: 'openid offline_access' // set the refresh token here
      }
    }
```